# iproute command: ip -6 rule show nothing even with kernel option IPV6_MULTIPLE_TABLES=y

Tags: linux-kernel, routing, ipv6

I want to enable my linux 3.2.4 to have ipv6 multi-routing table functionality. I enable IPV6_MULTIPLE_TABLES when make menuconfig and rebuild kernel.(Also with ip advanced routing and ip multi table)

I use `ip -6 rule`, it still didn't show local and main tables, that is ipv6 multi table didn't work.

Did Anyone have encounter the same problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done!
I forgot to replace old ipv6.ko module with the new one.

Comment: Please accept your solution :).